# PHP to load an HTML page while running an external script

Tags: php

I need to run an `index.php` script that calls an external script which takes a few seconds to run, before redirecting to `index.html`.  Is it possible for the php script to load the same `index.html` into the browser in the meantime so the screen isn't blank?  If not what would be the way to handle this?  My best effort is:

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTMLFile("index.html");
    echo $doc->saveHTML();
    shell_exec('./shellscript.sh');
    header('Location: index.html');
    exit;
?>
```

which fails to load with:

`Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag nav invalid in index.html, line: 33 in {pathto}/index.php on line 3`

That line of index.html is - `<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">`

Grateful for assistance.

Comment: This way it cannot work, because headers are sent before content.
You cannot send any content before finishing sending headers.

Comment: shell_exec() blocks, so header() wouldn't run until the shell script exits. you COULD try to run it in the background, e.g. `shell_exec('foo &')`, but then you couldn't wait for the results.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible. You can close the connection and run the command afterwards. This avoids the problem of `shell_exec` blocking processing.

It's a little bit tricky to get it to work but it's something like:

```
 ignore_user_abort(true); // prevent the PHP script from being killed when the connection closes
 header("Location: /index.html");
 header("Connection: Close");
 flush();
 // the connection should now be closed, the user is redirected to index.html
 shell_exec('./shellscript.sh');
```

If you're also sending content you might need to send a `Content-Length` header. If you're using sessions be sure to close the session with `session_close()`. You should also flush any output buffers.

---

The DOMDocument error you're getting is unrelated.

Comment: Looks promising but my browser is still held back while the script runs.

Comment: Try sending the `Content-Length` header.